# get-adgroupmember inconsistently returns group members

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been writing powershell since powershell 2, and I've run into something odd I've never seen before.

```
$groups = get-adgroup -filter {name -like 'SomeGroup*'} | select name | sort name

foreach ($group in $groups){
    $groupsid = $group.name
    write-host $groupsid
    Get-ADGroupMember $groupsid | select name | sort name
    write-host "`n`n"
}
```

The `get-adgroupmember` in the `foreach` loop is only enumerating members in certain groups and not in others.

If `"$groupsid" = "DeveloperGroup"` and I use
`get-adgroupmember DeveloperGroup | select name | sort name` in the shell,
then I get back what I expected to see: a list of group members.  But for several groups that are enumerated by the first line, I get nothing back when the exact same cmdlet is executed within the `foreach` loop.  I know some of the cmdlets are still a little buggy, just no idea why this is being intermittent in what the loop decides to fetch.

Comment: Make sure you’re running the session as admin. Had a similar issue before where only certain groups enumerate from regular session

Comment: Do you get the same results if you loop over the `member` property of each group ?

Comment: Hi, if any of the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited few lines of your cmdlet and it is working fine for me. Please use the below formatted PowerShell command to get your desire output.

```
$groups = get-adgroup -filter {name -like 'Group*'} | sort name
$results = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | select samaccountname, name, @{n='GroupName';e={$group}}, @{n='Description';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}} | sort name
}
$results
$results | Export-csv C:\GroupMemberShip.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Doug Maurer comment is helpful and may be part of the issue.

Another problem: avoid using the name of the group.
Either use the group object directly as input of the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet like below, or use the `DistinguishedName` property of the group.

```
foreach ($group in $groups){
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | select name | sort name
    write-host "`n`n"
}
```